# Is providing a <header> element enough to make a header recognisable to screen readers, or does it need a label?

Tags: html, accessibility

As good practice, I always introduce a `<header>` (or `<nav>`, or `<footer>`) with a visually hidden heading (https://css-tricks.com/inclusively-hidden/), for example:

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="inclusively-hidden">Header area</h1>
  ...
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Some interesting content</h1>
  ...
</main>
<footer>
  <h1 class="inclusively-hidden">Footer area</h1>
  ...
</footer>
```

I do this to make it easy for screen reader users to identify those contents, coming from a time where elements like `<header>` or `<footer>` did not yet exist:

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 class="inclusively-hidden">Header area</h1>
  ...
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Some interesting content</h1>
  ...
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <h1 class="inclusively-hidden">Footer area</h1>
  ...
</div>
```

Nowadays though we do have them, and here my question arises: according to WCAG 2.1 AA, would my code still be valid if I'd remove the visually hidden headings? In the content, however, headings still are meaningful and necessary.

```html
<header>
  ...
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Some interesting content</h1>
  ...
</main>
<footer>
  ...
</footer>
```

My argumentation would be: As I'm using only a single `<header>` and `<footer>` element, they can clearly be identified by screen readers as what they are. I would - for example - not place another `<header>` somewhere inside `<main>` or similar, as this would destroy the clarity/uniqueness of the elements:

```html
<header>
  ...
</header>
<main>
  <header><!-- Wouldn't add this here! -->
    <h1>Some interesting content</h1>
  </header>
  ...
</main>
<footer>
  ...
</footer>
```

I'm aware that for screen reader users, additional labelling would improve usability tremendously, be it by using visually hidden headings, or with an `aria-label`, or whatever. What I like about a thorough heading outline over the whole page is that I'm able to see all areas of a document reflected in the heading outline, and so I'm able to scan it quickly (ie. using `Insert + F7` in NVDA to display a tree view of the headings outline) and navigate between areas (using `H`, `Shift + H`, `1`, `Shift + 1`, etc.).

But speaking from a strictly technical point of view, I'd say visually headings are not necessary anymore nowadays in this scenario. Do you agree?

Comment: I even would argue that `<h1 class="inclusively-hidden">Header area</h1>` might not be that usefull. Often a visually hidden `<a>Skip to main content</a>` is better (which is actually used on many sites). [a11yproject.com](https://www.a11yproject.com) is IMHO a really good source for such informations.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! What I like about a thorough heading outline over the whole page is that I'm able to see all areas of a document reflected in the heading outline, and so I'm able to scan it quickly (ie. using `Insert + F7` in NVDA to display a tree view of the headings outline) and navigate between areas (using `H`, `Shift + H`, `1`, `Shift + 1`, etc.). A "Skip to main content" link doesn't make up for this.

Comment: Especially using  `h1` for those informations is proably a bad idea. `h1` should be a meaningfull text describing the contents of the page/section (similar to `title`). "Wasting" it for "Header area" which does not contain any really meaningfull infromation about the document is a bit contra productive. At least what I heard from differnt talks about that topic.

Comment: This is no longer true. You can use as many `<h1>` elements as you want these days, see Google's official answer video here: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/heading-tags-for-seo/341817/

Comment: Sorry I might have expressed myself wrong there. The `hN` give a table of contents for the reader. Where `h1` is at the top of it. If that contains only `Header area` it might not that helpful for the read because you now know ok it is a header but what does it contain?

Comment: Sure, the content of the heading could be more expressive. In a `<nav>`, for example, there could be several navigations (a content and a user navigation, for example), which could then be expressed in separate headings.

Comment: As I said I generally follow the structure the [a11yproject.com](https://www.a11yproject.com) itself has and their suggestions, as this site itself is often suggested by people with disabilities as source.

Comment: [Accessible heading structure](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-accessible-heading-structure/) (January 3, 2022) `Can I use multiple h1s on a web page? Short answer: No. The h1 is for the page title only. [...] Using multiple h1s was proposed with the introduction of the HTML Document Outline in HTML5 [...] The Document outline was never adapted by browsers or assistive technology [...]` and [github.com whatwg/html Issue #83: Suggest adding a warning about outline algorithm](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/83)

Comment: Your original code is fine.  `<header>` and `<footer>` are landmark regions, banner and contentinfo, respectively (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#landmark_roles), so the screen reader user can navigate by landmarks ('D' for NVDA and 'R' for JAWS) in addition to the other keys you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the `<h1>` headings.

Sectioning elements, like `<header>` or `<footer>` don't require the use of a heading element (e.g. `<h1>`), and including one is not a standard practice that I've observed.

You can use `aria-label` or `aria-labelled-by` on a sectioning element to set an accessible name, although it's typically unnecessary unless you have multiple sectioning elements of the same type (e.g. multiple `<footer>` elements).

As far as the multiple `<h1>` argument goes, I don't believe that there's anything in WCAG that prohibits this practice, as long as the headings are properly nested in a way that illustrates the logical hierarchy of the content structure.

Answer (score 0):

According to WCAG, you can remove the heading.

However, navigation by heading is still largely used, while navigation by landmark isn't that much used, according to [WebAim screen reader survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/).
Therefore, I would still keep the heading as it is now, regardless or not you are using header or footer regions, so that screen reader users can navigate efficiently using the two methods.